# How to change a position of the Popover component as part of the Select component in MUI 5?

Tags: material-ui, popover

I use a `Select` component (assume[this one](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-select/#chip)). By default, a `Popover` component appears just under the select field, but I want to place it on the right side. I'll describe below the ways I tried to achieve this behavior and how I failed every time. Keep in mind that I'm a newbie to the MUI.

1. The most proper way to change the position is to set up `anchorOrigin` and `transformOrigin` props, but it works only if you can access those props. The `Select` component makes the `Popover` on its own (or more precisely, a `Menu` component inside the `Select`) and doesn't provide an API to propagate props.
2. The `Menu` component has a `PopoverClasses` prop that propagates `classes` to the `Popover`, so I wanted to change position by overriding `left` and `top` styles with values calculated by JS. But no matter how hard I tried to figure out how it worked, I couldn't. Every guide I found uses `makeStyles` from `"@mui/styles"` or `createUseStyles` from `"react-jss"` which are deprecated since MUI v5. Is `classes` prop totally deprecated in MUI v5?
3. Adding styles like `"& .MuiPopover-root"` to `Select` or `Menu` didn't work too, because the `Popover` creates near the top of the DOM to work as a modal dialog and isn't a child of the `Select`.
4. Despite the `Menu` doesn't propagates props to the `Popover` directly, it propagate props to a `MenuList` which is a child of the `Popover`. Using `MenuListProps: {ref=myRef}` I can access to the DOM element of the `Popover` by `myRef.current.parentElement`. But it isn't enough, because I have no good event to override values. The `Popover` is created after a short period of time after an `onOpen` event fires of the `Select`, so during the event a value `myRef.current` is undefined, and after `setTimeout()` is too late - it's noticeably how `Popover` jumps.

It's too hard for such a simple action. Did I miss something obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Select` component you can propagate its `Popover` props through the `MenuProps` property.

It works because `Menu` actually propagates props to `Popover` and can accept all its properties, as described in [docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/menu/#props)

Example:

```js
<Select
  labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
  id="demo-simple-select"
  value={age}
  label="Age"
  onChange={handleChange}
  MenuProps={{
    anchorReference: "anchorPosition",
    anchorPosition: { top: 0, left: 475 }
  }}
>
  <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
</Select>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I will pay more attention to the "Props of the <component-name> are also available" message)